# Traversing mounted volumes to find specific file types

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

I am trying to figure out how to scan mounted volumes (they are attached to a server and they are mounted via afp:// onto my workstation) and pick out certain files types, and output the path, file name and asset id to a csv file. The asset id is the last 10 digits of the file name preceded by an "_" ( for example: **afilename_1234567890.mov**) Some files do not have an asset id (I ignore) and some files have multiple "."'s (for example, **afilename_videofile_23.98_prores_1234567890.mov**). I can get the volumes I need (less a time machine backup drive) but trying to scan for the files is troublesome. I have looked a various example and studied the Apple FileManager docs but there is nothing concrete.

I have the following routine to do what I need but with the line, **let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: url.path)!**, enumerator is always blank.

Either I am making a bad assumption or I am definitely missing something crucial.

```
func FindFilesWithAssetIDs() {

    // Find all the mounted volumes
    let keys: [URLResourceKey] = []
    let volumes = FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: keys, options: [])!

    var count = 0
    var volumeCount = volumes.count
    var volumeItem = 0

    let filterExtensions = ["mxf", "mov", "mp4", "scc", "cap", "srt", "txt", "rtf", "wav", "mp3", "m2v", "aif"]

    // Scan all the mounted volumes, one at a time
    for url in volumes {

        let components = url.pathComponents

        if components.count > 1  && components[1] == "Volumes" {
            if components[2] == "Time Machine Backup" { continue } // Check if the volume is the staff backup disk. If it is, move on to the next volume

            guard let volumeTypeKey = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeIsLocalKey]) else { return } // Make sure we are scanning the volumes and not any local folders like /private

            let volumeType: Bool = volumeTypeKey.volumeIsLocal!

            if volumeType == false {
                let fileManager = FileManager.default
                let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(atPath: url.path)!

                while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
                    if element.hasSuffix("mxf") || element.hasSuffix("mov") { // a test. I would much rather use a filterExtension method or a switch statement
                        // do something
                        count += 1
                    }
                }

                NSLog(url.path, " ", String(count))
                //                    NSLog(url.path)
            }
        }

        volumeItem += 1
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duh!! <facepalm>... The "App Sandbox" switch was turned on for some reason which prevented my code from accessing the network volumes. So, given the "element" variable, how can I filter out files starting with "." (invisible files) and is there a better way to filter files using the "filterExtensions" variable? Thanks

Comment: accepting answers to your previous questions would greatly encourage me to give a more detailed answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enumerating with nsfilemanager i'd suggested using NSMetadataQuery aka Spotlight. see here for an introduction: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryingMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001848-CJBEJBHH

Answer (score 0):

I tried using an Applescript to scan the volumes but there were a few files that, even though they existed, Spotlight couldn't find them. I rebuilt the Spotlight databases on all the mounted volumes but no luck. Because of the errors, I resorted to Swift.

At the end of the day, I am much farther ahead with Swift then Applescript. I have made a few changes to the code (**while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? String** is now **while let element = enumerator.nextObject() as? URL**) shortening other routines for String <-> URL calls and so on.

I am closing out this question as it has been resolved.